# VS 2010 Set up project - Installing exe through custom action

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, setup-deployment

I'm creating a **set up poject using VS 2010**. One of the third party exe should be installed through the custom action. I have done this and works fine. But requirement is to

1) First time when MSI is installed this exe should also be installed in target machine.(Added custom action under Install)

2) When the project is uninstalled this third party exe should not be uninstalled.(So basically no uninstall custom is needed for this exe)

3) If user uninstall the application and re-install again there should be a custom actionto  check if the thirt party exe is alredy installed. if not, install  else dont.

How can i do this ?

[image: Custom Action]

Answer (score 1):

3) Check the registry value, or the default install location.

2) Windows installer < 4.5 (<4.5 is practically everywhere) can't chain.

1) See 2.

Visual Studio 2012 drops setup projects completely anyway, so you won't need to rewrite.
(Hint) I wouldn't waste your time using InstallShield 2012 LE (VS 2012 default).

That's why I recommend you create your setup project with 
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/

**The freeware edition suffices.**
Here's an edition overview:
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/purchase.html

Comment: Thanks for the post, I have done 1 and 2, Im stuck with 3rd item.